# How to set grid lines in a one pixel width (WPF DataGrid)?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using the WPF datagrid to display some data and I want to grid lines thickness was equal to one pixel, but each cell displays unwanted border. How to get rid of it and set thickness of all lines to one pixel (like in DataGridView in WinForms)?

```
XAML:
<DataGrid HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionUnit="Cell">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>                                    
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Result:
[image: unwanted borders]

Comment: It might be OS specific, just tried sample at win10 and there is no such shadow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the solution! 
Settig parameter RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased"
Many thanks to David Kossoglyad for this solution.

```
<DataGrid RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" UseLayoutRounding="True" ....>
```

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick for you

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,0,0,1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: When I set property GridLinesVisibility to "None" value, all grid lines was removed.
I need grid lines, but in a one pixel width.

Comment: Problem is not solved, but exacerbated. After setting <DataGrid.CellStyle> 
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
borders become more thicker and now is equal 2 pixels

Comment: Just change 1,1,1,1 to 1,0,0,1 and see if it helps

Comment: It did not help.
When I set BorderThickness Value to "1,0,0,1", gird lines returned to its original state (as shown in the picture in my question)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="1" Opacity="0" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

If this wouldn't help try to set same property for `DataGrid.RowStyle`.

Comment: unfortunately did not help